# Not able to attach policy to a role using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Using BOTO3 script,Created a Role and a Policy and trying to attached policy to that role. I am getting error while attaching but if i do attach manually then working fine.

Using BOTO3 i am doing followings:
Created a AWS role say "TEST"
Created a policy called "POL"
Both have been created and we can see on AWS console. Now attaching policy to Role with below command

```
response = client.attach_role_policy(
    RoleName='TEST',
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::6929051012:policy/POL'
)
```

getting below error.

```
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException: An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the AttachRolePolicy operation: Policy arn:aws:iam::6929051012:policy/POL does not exist or is not attachable.
```

Manually i can attached this policy to Role.
Your Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm if the account number 6929051012 is valid and also are you trying to this attach role API call for same account or if its a different account?

Comment: If you go to the policy in the IAM console, does the displayed ARN match the one you are using?

Comment: @bdcloud i have not exposed actual acct number in thread but acct is valid one. I logged in as root user created Role and policy with same user.  If i see Role arn it shows ```arn:aws:iam::6929051012:role/TEST``` and policy shows ```arn:aws:iam::6929051012:policy/POL```

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it shows same, i even copied ARN and pasted in script.

Comment: Is your Python programming using AWS credentials from the same account as the policy?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, it is same account(root acct)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, it is same account(root acct)

Comment: You might want to try it _without_ using root credentials. Create an IAM User, assign it appropriate permissions (eg Admin), then generate credentials for the user and use them with your Python app (eg via `aws configure`). Generally, it is recommended not to use root credentials except for things that only root can use.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created an IAM Role (`stack-role`) via the management console
- Created an IAM Policy via the management console (`arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/stack-policy`)

I then ran:

```
import boto3

iam_client = boto3.client('iam')

response = iam_client.attach_role_policy(
    RoleName='stack-role',
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/stack-policy'
)

print (response)
```

The call returned successfully. I then looked at the Role in the IAM management console and the `stack-policy` was attached.

So, seems to work fine!

Comment: Yes, it suppose to be working fine but my case that error i am still getting.